# SVG ANIMATION (ICO to SVG file)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to animate my SVG, I converted it with an online converter from .ICO to .SVG, problem now is I cant animate the strokedasharray and the strokedashoffset. Im trying to create an animation in the codepen link below, making my SVG look like that, I trie using the fill but it isn't working, anyway to resolve this. my SVG code is below. I'll be so glad if i can be assisted with this, i cant use illustrator, I'm just new into development
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/bGyoz

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="56.000000px" height="56.000000px" viewBox="0 0 256.000000 256.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,256.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M670 2485 c0 -8 -7 -15 -15 -15 -9 0 -18 -7 -21 -15 -4 -8 -17 -15
-30 -15 -14 0 -27 -7 -30 -15 -4 -8 -17 -15 -30 -15 -14 0 -27 -7 -30 -15 -4
-8 -17 -15 -30 -15 -14 0 -27 -7 -30 -15 -4 -8 -12 -15 -20 -15 -8 0 -14 -7
-14 -15 0 -9 -9 -15 -25 -15 -14 0 -28 -7 -31 -15 -4 -8 -17 -15 -30 -15 -14
0 -27 -7 -30 -15 -4 -8 -17 -15 -30 -15 -14 0 -27 -7 -30 -15 -4 -8 -12 -15
-20 -15 -8 0 -14 -7 -14 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -19 0 -30 -5 -30 -14 0 -8
-11 -17 -25 -20 -14 -4 -34 -14 -45 -23 -19 -17 -20 -31 -20 -385 0 -320 2
-368 15 -368 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -10 10
-15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -8 7
-15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10
-15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -8 7
-15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10
-15 29 -15 21 0 30 -6 35 -22 3 -13 6 -157 6 -320 0 -258 2 -298 15 -298 8 0
15 -7 15 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -8 5 -15 11 -15 6 0 17 -7
25 -15 9 -8 24 -15 35 -15 10 0 19 -7 19 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5
30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5
30 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30
-15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30
-15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30
-15 0 -11 11 -15 40 -15 29 0 40 4 40 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0
10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 10 10 15 30
15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0
30 5 30 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0
10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8 9 15 19 15 11 0 26 7 35 15 8 8 19 15 25
15 6 0 11 7 11 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 13 0 15 40
15 298 0 163 3 307 6 320 5 16 14 22 35 22 19 0 29 5 29 15 0 10 10 15 30 15
20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30
15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8 7
15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15
20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 13 0 15 48 15
368 0 354 -1 368 -20 385 -11 9 -31 19 -45 23 -14 3 -25 12 -25 20 0 9 -11 14
-30 14 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 8 -6 15 -14 15 -8 0 -16 7 -20 15 -3 8 -16 15
-30 15 -13 0 -26 7 -30 15 -3 8 -16 15 -30 15 -13 0 -26 7 -30 15 -3 8 -17 15
-31 15 -16 0 -25 6 -25 15 0 8 -6 15 -14 15 -8 0 -16 7 -20 15 -3 8 -16 15
-30 15 -13 0 -26 7 -30 15 -3 8 -16 15 -30 15 -13 0 -26 7 -30 15 -3 8 -16 15
-30 15 -13 0 -26 7 -30 15 -3 8 -12 15 -21 15 -8 0 -15 7 -15 15 0 11 -11 15
-40 15 -29 0 -40 -4 -40 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -8
-7 -15 -15 -15 -8 0 -15 -7 -15 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30
-15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -8 -7 -15 -15 -15 -8 0 -15
-7 -15 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -8 -7 -15 -15 -15
-8 0 -15 -7 -15 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -8 -7 -15
-15 -15 -8 0 -15 -7 -15 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0
-11 -12 -15 -50 -15 -38 0 -50 4 -50 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30
15 0 8 -7 15 -15 15 -8 0 -15 7 -15 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15
0 8 -7 15 -15 15 -8 0 -15 7 -15 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0
8 -7 15 -15 15 -8 0 -15 7 -15 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 10
-10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 8 -7 15 -15 15 -8 0 -15 7 -15 15 0 10
-10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 11 -11 15 -40 15 -29 0 -40 -4 -40 -15z
m120 -240 c0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30
-5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30
-5 30 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5
30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 13 0 15 -39
15 -290 l0 -290 -29 0 c-16 0 -31 -6 -35 -15 -3 -8 -16 -15 -30 -15 -13 0 -26
-7 -30 -15 -3 -8 -16 -15 -28 -15 -13 -1 -34 -14 -48 -30 -13 -17 -34 -30 -46
-30 -12 0 -24 -7 -28 -15 -3 -8 -16 -15 -30 -15 -13 0 -26 -7 -30 -15 -3 -8
-16 -15 -30 -15 -13 0 -26 -7 -30 -15 -8 -22 -156 -22 -156 0 0 10 -10 15 -30
15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 8 -7 15 -15 15 -8 0 -15 7 -15 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15
-20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15
-20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 8 -7 15 -15 15 -8 0 -15 7 -15 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15
-28 0 -30 3 -30 35 0 24 -5 35 -15 35 -13 0 -15 33 -15 235 0 202 2 235 15
235 8 0 15 9 15 20 0 11 7 20 15 20 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7
15 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0
10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 10 10 15 30
15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 12 14 15 65 15 51 0
65 -3 65 -15z m1110 0 c0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15
30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30
-15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30
-15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7 15 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15
8 0 15 -9 15 -20 0 -11 7 -20 15 -20 13 0 15 -33 15 -235 0 -202 -2 -235 -15
-235 -10 0 -15 -11 -15 -35 0 -24 -5 -35 -15 -35 -8 0 -15 -7 -15 -15 0 -10
-10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30
-15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0
-30 -5 -30 -15 0 -8 -7 -15 -15 -15 -8 0 -15 -7 -15 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30
-15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -22 -148 -22 -156 0 -4 8 -17 15 -30 15 -14 0 -27
7 -30 15 -4 8 -17 15 -30 15 -14 0 -27 7 -30 15 -4 8 -16 15 -28 15 -12 0 -33
13 -46 30 -14 16 -35 29 -48 30 -12 0 -25 7 -28 15 -4 8 -17 15 -30 15 -14 0
-27 7 -30 15 -4 9 -19 15 -35 15 l-29 0 0 290 c0 251 2 290 15 290 8 0 15 7
15 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8
7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15
20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15
15 0 12 14 15 65 15 51 0 65 -3 65 -15z m-540 -960 c0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0
30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15
-7 15 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30
-5 30 -15 0 -10 10 -15 30 -15 20 0 30 -5 30 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 8 0 15 -7
15 -15 0 -8 7 -15 15 -15 13 0 15 -37 15 -275 0 -238 -2 -275 -15 -275 -8 0
-15 -7 -15 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30
-15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -10
-10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -8 -7 -15 -15 -15 -8 0 -15 -7 -15
-15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0 -30 -5 -30 -15 0 -10 -10 -15 -30 -15 -20 0
-30 -5 -30 -15 0 -11 -12 -15 -50 -15 -38 0 -50 4 -50 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15
-20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 8 -7 15 -15 15
-8 0 -15 7 -15 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15
-20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15 -20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 10 -10 15 -30 15
-20 0 -30 5 -30 15 0 8 -7 15 -15 15 -13 0 -15 37 -15 275 0 238 2 275 15 275
8 0 15 7 15 15 0 8 7 15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30
15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 8 7
15 15 15 8 0 15 7 15 15 0 10 10 15 30 15 20 0 30 5 30 15 0 10 10 15 30 15
20 0 30 5 30 15 0 12 16 15 80 15 64 0 80 -3 80 -15z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: the g element has stroke="none" so there's no stroke to animate in the first place.

Comment: Good day, like i said i am new to development, just my first SVG animation I'm trying to do so i read an article and just took what I got from it then practiced it. can you kindly help, I will be glad, tried everything I know even kept a stroke with my CSS in it, I'm beginning to think its cus i converted it with an online converter?

Comment: You have now a filled shape instead of having a stroked one. Besides the drawing is way more complicated than it should be. Probably because the .ico was pixelated and now you have lots of small bumps (Bezier curves).  Remove the width and the height of the svg element to understand what I mean.I would redraw the thing from scratch.

Comment: @enxaneta yh i just did what you suggested, the whole element vanished as I thought it would, but I don't know how to use illustrator yet for scalar graphics, the deign concept is a representation of my name and I'm trying to build something like that for my portfolio?

Comment: @enxaneta sorry do you plan on assisting me draw it from scratch?

Comment: If you want to draw something from scratch and you don't know SVG then download and use an SVG editor such as Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this reshaped svg that I did in Inkscape. Is not a good idea to convert bitmap images into svg due to the fact of pixelization. Your svg look awfully pixelated due to that. Inkscape is a native svg editor you can use to impor the bitmap icon and reshape just by drawing it all over.

Now, concerning to the animation, try with this and you'll get what you want. Note that I have created a single path closed path.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 256">
  <path class="path" d="m 15.625507,46.199537 55.767886,-32.030352 55.623047,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311586 0.14485,-64.311586 55.76788,-32.030352 55.62305,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311579 -55.76788,32.03036 -55.62305,-32.28123 55.62305,32.28123 -0.14485,64.31158 -55.76788,32.03035 L 70.958866,207.10393 71.103708,142.79235 126.87159,110.762 71.103708,142.79235 15.480664,110.51112 Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#000;stroke-width:13;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-linecap:round" />
</svg>
```

```css
.path {
    stroke-linejoin:round;
    stroke-linecap:round;
    stroke-dasharray: 1500;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
    animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
    }

    @keyframes dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodePen - Basic Example of SVG Line Drawing, Backward and Forward</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <svg viewBox="0 0 256 256">
    <path class="path" fill="#fff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="13" d="m 15.625507,46.199537 55.767886,-32.030352 55.623047,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311586 0.14485,-64.311586 55.76788,-32.030352 55.62305,32.281229 -0.14485,64.311579 -55.76788,32.03036 -55.62305,-32.28123 55.62305,32.28123 -0.14485,64.31158 -55.76788,32.03035 L 70.958866,207.10393 71.103708,142.79235 126.87159,110.762 71.103708,142.79235 15.480664,110.51112 Z"/>
    </svg>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: As an extra tip there are many nice js libraries to animate svgs, I personally have used vivus, anime, GSAP. Some other are listed here https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/javascript-libraries-animate-svg/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjJka6W0IXyAhX8m2oFHbTnDO0QFjAFegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2BSujGLWq9oy-R79zJX77u